# if statement checking if they are the same

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm getting a list from a file on my computer

I am seeing if the name in the file equals a certain name

```
for i in names:
if names[i] == "paaches":
    NotTaken.append(names(i))
else:
    print(i)
```

but i keep getting this

```
    File "/Users/rj-mac/Desktop/python/learn.py", line 10, in <module>
    if names[i] == "paaches":
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

my whole code

```
 names = open("usernames.txt").readlines()
NotTaken = []


    for i in names:
        if i == "paaches":
            NotTaken.append(names[i])
        else:
            pass
    print(NotTaken)

    usernames.txt

    paaches
    testuser
    notueser
```

Comment: `i` in this case is the name, and not the index, so your code should be `if i == "paaches":`

Comment: please repair the format of the text you added

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You have to use `strip()` to do this because `readlines()` will output a list like `['paaches\n', 'testuser\n', 'notueser']`:

```
names = open("usernames.txt").readlines()
NotTaken = []
for i in names:
    if i.strip() == "paaches":
        NotTaken.append(i.strip())
    else:
        pass
print(NotTaken)
```

Output:

```
['paaches']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read the error, it's saying your indices (or index) for your list cannot be a string. This means your `for` loop is returning a string for `i`, which is an invalid index for a list.

The way `for` loops work in python is if you have a list:

`l = ["item1", "item2", "item3"]`

Doing the following will print `item` for each item in the list `l`:

```
for item in l:
    print item
```

So, instead of checking for `names[i]`, just check if `i` is equal to `"paaches"`, and append `i` (not `names[i]`) if it matches:

```
for i in names:
    if i == "paaches":
        NotTaken.append(i)
    else:
        print(i)
```

***EDIT***

The reason it's not working for you is because when you do `names = open("filename.txt").readlines()`, each item in the `names` list will have `\n` at the end (i.e. the list will be `names = ["paaches\n", "testuser\n", "notueser\n"]`).

To fix this, use `rstrip()` (strips newlines and spaces at the end of a string) after you read your file:

```
names = open("usernames.txt").readlines()
new_names = []
for name in names:
    name = name.rstrip()
    new_names.append(name)
```

Then you can use your `for` loop:

```
for i in new_names:
    if i == "paaches":
        NotTaken.append(i)
    else:
        print(i)
```

Comment: Should not you append `i`  instead of `names(i)`?

Comment: That's not working, I think it's checking if the element like [0] is equal to paaches, not checking if the string is equal to paaches,

Comment: Nope, it is checking if `i` (or the current string being iterated from `names`) is equal to `paaches` - that's how python works. If you include the full list of `names` in your OP we can verify if there is another issue.

Comment: Edited mine @user9984190